# Multiple login forms on Android app

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

My application will allow user to log in using  Email, Twitter or Facebook. I'm using Facebook Android SDK on its last version.

How can I check if a user is already logged in at the onCreate method so I can display the login options if the user is logged out or redirect to the main activity if he is logged in?

I'm currently using the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
// this method is not run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
  // You have an active cached session
}
```

That is probably the best way to detect.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my library https://github.com/antonkrasov/AndroidSocialNetworks

It allows you easily implement login for Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Google Plus.